# vscode extension quickpick activeItems doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

```js
const q = vscode.window.createQuickPick();
q.items = [{ label: "1" }, { label: "2" }];
q.activeItems = [{ label: "2" }];
q.show();
```

Based on my understand of vscode extension api doc.

```
/**
  * Active items. This can be read and updated by the extension.
  */
activeItems: readonly T[];
```

it should active "2" item when quickpick is showing.
But I found activeItems will reset after show() method;
I dont know why and cant find any same issue in the internet,

Answer (score 0):

it seems that a [bug is impacting behavior here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75005)

my solution was to set the active items *after* calling the show method. Also it seems the code does reference comparisons.

So

```
const q = vscode.window.createQuickPick();
const selectedItem = { label: "2" };
q.items = [{ label: "1" }, selectedItem];
q.show();
q.activeItems = [selectedItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and I think I've found the underlying problem. It looks like the underlying VSCode logic will filter your assignment to `activeItems` based on membership in `items`, and it looks like it may be an identity check rather than a structural check.

Changing my code to be something like:

```
quickPick.items = ...
quickPick.activeItems = quickPick.items.filter((item) => ...);
```

seemed to get the expected behavior (allowing an initial active item to be set for the QuickPick).

So in your case you could try:

```
const q = vscode.window.createQuickPick();
q.items = [{ label: "1" }, { label: "2" }];
q.activeItems = [q.items[1]];
// Or e.g.:
// q.activeItems = q.items.filter((item) => item.label === "2");
q.show();
```

I know it's a year later but maybe this will help someone else who stumbles upon this issue :)